# Command line YouTube in VLC player - quality control?

Tags: command-line, youtube, vlc

I'm trying to make a little script which involves playing YouTube videos from the command line using VLC. I'm using Windows 7 with VLC in the search path.

Typing

```
vlc http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0faacLn8K4
```

plays the video, but always at the highest quality. In the internet browser, appending the term '&fmt=18' forces a low-resolution mode. However, using this in the command line,

```
vlc http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0faacLn8K4&fmt=18
```

gives an error:

```
´fmt´ is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've tried quoting the url with various quotes, to no avail. The entire link gets passed to VLC, including the quotes.

What's the solution to this? Is there a VLC switch for selecting stream quality? The [VLC command-line help](http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help) may have the answer, but understanding the meaning of all the switches is a little beyond me.

Music credit: By Your Side by Breakbot

Comment: from VLC directory , vlc "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0faacLn8K4&fmt=18"  works for me

Comment: Hm yeah. Cool. Although it does need to be a full url with "http://www.youtube.com/..." (Looks like your http has just been parsed, and it's been removed..) Not sure what I did wrong when I tried with those quotes! Make it an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: done.. may be spaces in command lines might be a reason..

Comment: This is because `&` has special meaning in the shell, so it actually executes `vlc http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0faacLn8K4` and then runs `fmt=18` as a second command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to VLC directory from command prompt and then type

```
vlc "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0faacLn8K4&fmt=18"
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Streamlink](https://streamlink.github.io/):

```
pipx install streamlink
```

Send the stream to `cvlc --fullscreen`:

```
streamlink --player="cvlc --fullscreen" "https://www.youtube.com/freecodecamp/live" best
```

To save bandwidth you could use `worst` instead of `best`.
Also posted [here](https://superuser.com/a/1412778/500826).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to run from the command line?

If you just start VLC itself then use 'ctrl+N' to open an 'Open Media' dialogue, which will be on the network tab, you can enter the url + the "&fmt=18" in the "Please enter a network URL:" area.

ie just the full path without any quotes.

Works with my VLC version 2.2.1.